# Unbiased estimator with only a error term

Tags: econometrics

I'm having some issues wrapping my head around an issue I stepped upon looking at an old exam. We have the following model:

```
y(i) = Beta + u(i)
u(i)~N(0, sigma^2)
```

Gauss-Markov Assumptions all hold. 
We are then asked to show that we have an unbiased estimator of beta using the mean of y ($\frac{\sum y}{n}$). This holds. However, later we're asked if we chose y(m) to estimate our beta parameter - where m is the highest value of the sample -, would the estimator still be unbiased?
The student's answer is "No, because y(m) > mean of y, and if mean of y is unbiased, y(m) can not also be". Student got full points for this answer.

But if the only things that y depend on are Beta and and error term with expected value of zero, wouldn't $E[y(m)]$ = E[mean of y].

Comment: Welcome to the site! This should have the self-study tag (see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), and the question would be more readable if you wrote the equations with proper math formatting (see stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). With these changes, I think this is already a well-written self-study question containing enough of your own thoughts.

Comment: Although your description of $m$ is unclear, it appears you are asking why the expected value of the largest of $n$ independent random values exceeds the expected value of their mean.  Since in any realization the largest is no less than the mean, isn't this result trivial?

Answer (score 0):

The expected value of a random draw from the distribution will equal the mean, but if you purposefully select the maximum value in the sample then that no longer holds. The value of the max will be at least as large as the rest.